How do I wrap some child elements in a parent div when the parent div is a repeating element
I have a repeating set of divs, I don’t know how many of these there will be. Within each div there is some content and I want to wrap 2 specific a tags in a div for each parent div
Current markup:
<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <a class="link-b">link a</a>
    <a class="link-c">link a</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <a class="link-b">link a</a>
    <a class="link-c">link a</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <a class="link-b">link a</a>
    <a class="link-c">link a</a>
</div>

... and so on
Desired markup:
<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <div class="wrapped">
        <a class="link-b">link a</a>
        <a class="link-c">link a</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <div class="wrapped">
        <a class="link-b">link a</a>
        <a class="link-c">link a</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <p>text</p>
    <a class="link-a">link a</a>
    <div class="wrapped">
        <a class="link-b">link a</a>
        <a class="link-c">link a</a>
    </div>
</div>

... and so on
I have tried this:
$('.item .link-b, .item .link-c').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
But that results in all the links being wrapped in one div.wrapped in the first item.

Your code is close.You need to use $.each() loop over .item like this:
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.item').each(function() {
     $(this).find('.link-b,.link-c').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
   });
});

Working snippet:


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.link-b,.link-c').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
  });
});
.wrapped {
  background: grey;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link b</a>
  <a class="link-c">link c</a>
</div>




What this wrapAll does is to "extract then insert" into the first one as siblings i.e.

The structure will be wrapped around all of the elements in the set of
matched elements, as a single group.

from here; https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/
There are a number of ways to select the two elements and make them a "group" depending on need then wrap that "group".
Here are a few commented out and using the last one.


/* // get the last two anchor elements
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).find('a').slice("-2")
    .wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
});
*/
/* // get last two anchor with class starting with
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).find("a[class^='link-']").slice("-2")
    .wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
});
*/
/* // specific classes
$('.item').each(function() {
  $(this).find(".link-b,.link-c")
    .wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
});
*/

$('.item')// siblings after the one with a class link-a
  .find('.link-a').each(function() {
    $(this).nextAll()
      .wrapAll('<div class="wrapped" />');
  });
.wrapped {
  background-color: #00ff0020;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.wrapped>* {
  background-color: pink;
  border: 1px solid #FF0000;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link A</a>
  <a class="link-c">link AA</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link A</a>
  <a class="link-c">link AA</a>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <p>text</p>
  <a class="link-a">link a</a>
  <a class="link-b">link A</a>
  <a class="link-c">link AA</a>
</div>



